# MySQL Join statement

Tags: sql, mysql

I know how to get a single record from multiple tables using Join. How do you get multiple records?

E.G

**Table: categories**

```
id
name
description
```

**Table: some_table**

```
id
name
content
category_id
```

How would I extend the basic query below to pull all records from within all categories?

```
SELECT c.id, c.name as category_name FROM categories AS c
```

Comment: How would you go about getting a single record from multiple tables?

Comment: SELECT s.id, s.name, s.content, c.name as category_name FROM some_table AS s LEFT JOIN categories as c ON s.category_id = c.id WHERE s.id=1

Comment: That would get a single record. I want to get all categories and all records associated with each category.

Comment: So what if you leave off that WHERE clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact join depends on your needs, but the following will show all data from category and some_table where there is at least one row in some_table that matches the value in category.  Empty categories will not be shown; you can use a LEFT JOIN instead if you want to show empty category records with NULL values for the records that would otherwise come from the some_table table.

```
SELECT *
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN some_table st ON (c.id = st.category_id);
```